# Having same name for multiple variables (loop)

Tags: javascript, loops, blogger

I am using blogger. The blogger returns a unique value for <data:post.id/> (postId) on each iteration. What I want to do is, I need to save that value in a var and need to use it on each iteration.

```
var mathew=&#39;#&#39; + &#39;<data:post.id/>&#39;;
<a class='answer' href='javascript: void 0;' onclick='$(mathew).slideToggle(&apos;slow&apos;)'>View Answer</a>
```

PS: Its working when there is not more than 1 iteration.

Additional Info:
The loop is the post loop of blogger. Each time it gives a unique value for <data:post.id/>
I need to use that value in $(VALUE).slideToggle(&amp;apos;slow&amp;apos;) for each iteration.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense (looks like a mix of JS and HTML) and where is the loop? If you just give us seemingly random code, we are unable to help you. Please provide a proper explanation of your problem and a better example of your code.

Comment: @FelixKling the loop is the post loop of blogger. Each time it gives a unique value for &lt;data:post.id/&gt;. I need to use that value in $(VALUE).slideToggle(&amp;amp;apos;slow&amp;amp;apos;) for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you don't *need* the post ID at all.

Also, inline JavaScript should be avoided. [Read up on unobtrusive JavaScript.](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.answer').on('click', function () { 
        $(this).slideToggle('slow'); 
    });
});
```